# How to create multiple instance(new) of a class within other class?

Tags: python, class, object, instance, multiple-instances

I am trying to create multiple instances of a class, that is being used within multiple instances of a another class as below code.

I would like to use 'nodeInfo' class as a data type only in python to store different values for any instance that initialize it, so easily used within other instances that formed from another class 'Build'.

However, Here in the code, instances of 'test1', 'test2' and 'test3' of variables 'a' and 'b' are shared same value of nodeInfo class.

Could you help me to use a class nodeInfo as only data type? So I can store different values?

I hope my question is clear. Many thanks for your help in advance.

```
class nodeInfo(object):
    itemValues = {
                "attributes" : [],
                "values"     : []
                 }

    def __init__(self, attributes, values):
        print "calling constructor of nodeInfo Class"
        self.itemValues["attributes"] = attributes
        self.itemValues["values"] = values


class Build(object):
    v = ''
    a = nodeInfo
    b = nodeInfo

    def __init__(self, name):
        a = nodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        b = nodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        v = name

    def setItem(self, attribute, value):
        self.a = nodeInfo(attribute, value)


test = Build("a")
test2 = Build("b")
test3 = Build("c")

print test.a.itemValues, test2.a.itemValues, test3.a.itemValues

#test.setItem([3,2,1], [3,2,1])
#test2.a.itemValues = nodeInfo([3,2,1], [3,2,1])
test3.setItem([3,2,1], [3,2,1])

print test.a.itemValues, test2.a.itemValues, test3.a.itemValues
```

Result:

```
calling constructor of nodeInfo Class
{'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]}
calling constructor of nodeInfo Class
{'attributes': [3, 2, 1], 'values': [3, 2, 1]} {'attributes': [3, 2, 1], 'values': [3, 2, 1]} {'attributes': [3, 2, 1], 'values': [3, 2, 1]}
```

**It should be**:

```
calling constructor of nodeInfo Class
{'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]}
calling constructor of nodeInfo Class
{'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [3, 2, 1], 'values': [3, 2, 1]}
```

Comment: in the __init__ of Build, try self.a = ... self.b =

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Eric. However, the result is same as above.

Comment: Your `results` do not match the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *declare* `itemValues` outside of `NodeInfo.__init__` you are creating a class attribute that will be shared by all `NodeInfo` instances.

If you want `NodeInfo.itemValues` to be an instance attribute, with unique *values* (objects) for each instance, it needs to be *created* in the `__init__` method.

```
class NodeInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, attributes, values):
        # print "calling constructor of NodeInfo Class"
        self.itemValues = dict()
        self.itemValues["attributes"] = attributes
        self.itemValues["values"] = values
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.itemValues)
```

To assign values to an instance attribute you need to use `self.attribute = ...`.   You are missing that in `Build.__init__`.

```
class Build(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.a = NodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        self.b = NodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        self.v = name

    def setItem(self, attribute, value):
        self.a = NodeInfo(attribute, value)
```

Usage:

```
>>> test = Build('a')
>>> test2 = Build('b')
>>> print '{}:{}   ---   {}:{}'.format(test.v, test.a, test2.v, test2.a)
a:{'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]}   ---   b:{'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]}
>>>
>>> test2.setItem(['x', 'y', 'z'], ['c', 'b', 'a'])
>>>
>>> print '{}:{}   ---   {}:{}'.format(test.v, test.a, test2.v, test2.a)
a:{'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]}   ---   b:{'attributes': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'values': ['c', 'b', 'a']}
>>>
```

Have a look through the [Python Tutorial - 9. Classes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#classes).  When you get to the end of 9.3 you willll find a similar example of your problem.  Suggest you read the entire section, 9, 9.1 and 9.2 are important concepts for Python.

Comment: Many thanks for the exact answer :D Thanks for teaching the proper way for doing this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove declaration from Build for a and b

When you declare class members like this they are considered as static members and are shared across all class instances

then your constructor has to reference a and b as self.a and self.b, otherwise they will be treated as local variables

EDIT:

```
class Build(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.a = nodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        self.b = nodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        self.v = name

    def setItem(self, attribute, value):
        self.a = nodeInfo(attribute, value)

    def getItemA(self):
        return self.a

    def getItemB(self):
        return self.b
```

==================================================

Thanks for that. Here is actual result & code, it regards same nodeInfo is static. What I found is if I am not using nodeInfo and creating an instance with dict to Build. It is not used as static, but in this case we loose already defined data type.

Result:
{'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]} {'attributes': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [1, 2, 3]}
calling constructor of nodeInfo Class
{'attributes': [3, 2, 1], 'values': [3, 2, 1]} {'attributes': [3, 2, 1], 'values': [3, 2, 1]} {'attributes': [3, 2, 1], 'values': [3, 2, 1]}

Code:

```
__author__ = 'j'
class nodeInfo(object):
    itemValues = {
                "attributes" : [],
                "values"     : []
                 }

    def __init__(self, attributes, values):
        print "calling constructor of nodeInfo Class"
        self.itemValues["attributes"] = attributes
        self.itemValues["values"] = values

class Build(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.a = nodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        self.b = nodeInfo([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        self.v = name

    def setItem(self, attribute, value):
        self.a = nodeInfo(attribute, value)

    def getItemA(self):
        return self.a

    def getItemB(self):
        return self.b

test = Build(1)
test2 = Build(2)
test3 = Build(3)

test.setItem([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
print test.getItemA().itemValues, test2.getItemA().itemValues, test3.getItemA().itemValues

test3.setItem([3,2,1], [3,2,1])

print test.getItemA().itemValues, test2.getItemA().itemValues, test3.getItemA().itemValues
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I ask example code? if removed the declare in Build how we can avoid AttributeError: 'Build' object has no attribute 'a'?

Comment: I'll assume that this is in the print statement. Try introducing getA(), getB() to build and return self.a, self.b

Comment: Thanks for another suggestion. However, it still the same...
1. Removed __init__ in Build
2. created getA/getB in Build to return a and b
Still the nodeInfo instance is used as static